# Forming insert into query using rimpala in R

Tags: sql, r, impala

I am trying to execute `insert into` query on impala table using `rimpala.query()` function through `R` but I am getting an error. The query that I am executing is:

```
for(x in nrow)
{
    rite <- paste("INSERT INTO table1 (account_no, data_id, date_id, industry_no, sales_no, sales) VALUES (1445367,",data_frame1$data_id[x] ,",25,11346,23,", data_frame1$sales[x], ")",sep="")
    sql <- rimpala.query(rite);

}
```

where `data_frame1` is the data frame which has bunch of rows and `nrow` is the number of rows in `data_frame1`. The first `insert into` statement executes and fist data is inserted into database but it throws an error just after executing that as

`Error in rimpala.query(sql) : SQL error Error: The query did not generate a result set!`

How do I remove this error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `impala` but it seems that you need to use `paste0` maybe? Something like: `sql <- rimpala.query(paste0("INSERT INTO table1 (account_no, data_id, date_id, industry_no, sales_no, sales) VALUES (1445367,",data_frame1$data_id[x] ,",25,11346,23,", data_frame1$sales[x], ")"))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I executed the query you mentioned but it gives error as: `SQL error Error: The query did not generate a result set`

Comment: You probably have an error in your `sql` code then. It doesn't look like an R issue

Comment: what kind of error it could be? The same sql statement is working fine with postgrsql.

Comment: The SQL is fine. The problem is in the driver. See below.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in the [RImpala](https://github.com/austincv/RImpala) client, which is using [executeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) to run all queries, even those that modify state. They should be using [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) for DDL and INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/austincv/RImpala/issues/1) upstream for you.

Comment: thanks for the upstream. I hope that issue gets fixed soon as I kinda needed it urgently

Comment: Does this work yet? It'd be very helpful to do an `insert` with rImpala