# RImpala: Query Failed When Larger Data

Tags: r, impala

```
check1<-rimpala.query("select * from sum2")
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
```

dim(sum2) is 49501 rows and 18 columns.

```
check1<-rimpala.query("select *from sum3")
```

dim(sum3) is 102 rows and 6 columns.

It worked with smaller sample size.

sorry that I cant reproduce example to this. Is anyone encounter the same problem with larger data size? Any idea to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430351/forming-insert-into-query-using-rimpala-in-r/25459209#25459209), RImpala does not implement `executeUpdate` and so cannot run any query that modifies state. I suspect you hit your error not by running a larger SELECT query but rather because you tried to insert, update, or delete some data.

If you'd like to use Impala from R, I'd recommend using [dplyrimpaladb](https://github.com/jwills/dplyrimpaladb).

Answer (score 0):

RImpala (v0.1.6) build is updated with the support to execute DDL queries using executeUpdate.

The latest build contains the following fixes / additions:

1. Support for DDL query execution.
2. fetchSize parameter in query function to state the number of records that can be retrieved in one round trip read from Impala.
3. Fix for query failing when NULL values are being returned.
4. Compatiblity with CDH 5.x.x

You can run DDL queries using the query function as illustrated below:

```
rimpala.query(Q="drop table sample_table",isDDL="true")
```

You can also specify the fetchSize in the query function to aid reading large data efficiently.

```
rimpala.query(Q="select * from sample_table",fetchSize="10000")
```

Please find the latest build in Cran : http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RImpala/index.html

Source Code : https://github.com/Mu-Sigma/RImpala

Comment: But are you actually able to insert batch rows?  That was the original limitation I think

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the RImpala package and recommend to use the RJDBC package:

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
          classPath = list.files("path_to_jars",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),
          identifier.quote="`")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://localhost:21050/;auth=noSasl")
check1 <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select *from sum3")
```

I used these jar files an evenything works as expected:
https://downloads.cloudera.com/impala-jdbc/impala-jdbc-0.5-2.zip

For more information and a speed comparison look at this blog post:
http://datascience.la/r-and-impala-its-better-to-kiss-than-using-java/

Comment: But that has nothing to do with inserting rows.  Are you able to insert rows?