# Inserting data in to Impala with R JDBC

Tags: r, jdbc, insert, cloudera, impala

Does anyone know if it is possible to insert a whole table (data frame, matrix, whatever) into Impala using R with JDBC (Or not with JDBC then)?   We can select from Impala easily.

Comment: check out RImpala package?
check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430351/forming-insert-into-query-using-rimpala-in-r
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213022/rimpala-query-failed-when-larger-data

Comment: None of those links clearly answer my question and that is why I asked it. Not even the RImpala documentation says it clearly. The reason behind wanting to hear if it is actually possible, is that I have been trying different things already and am not clear on the limitations.

Comment: maybe pm/attract @Jeff Hammerbacher (@"Jeff Hammerbacher") attention? he might be able to resolve your issue :)

Comment: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/12/how-to-do-statistical-analysis-with-impala-and-r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#update dqm_results table

dbExecute(impala,"INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(1, 'test', 523, 'test_value')
```

Comment: When you are working with a table of 1.6M x 55 this function is extremely slow, do you know another way to insert values from R to Impala?

Comment: @HenryNavarro You can try to save your dataframe as a csv or txt file and then upload the file using `LOAD DATA ` statement. You can refer [this](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/impala_load_data.html) for more details.